# Can't remove list element defined inside class?

Tags: list, dart, element

I can't seem to remove an element from a List defined inside a class:

```
class something {

 List<int> numbers = [
  70,
  80,
  90,
 ];

 void PrintElementTwVo() {
  print(numbers[2]);
 }
 
 void RemoveElement() {
  PrintElementTwo(); // prints 80
  numbers.remove(2); // should remove 80
  PrintElementTwo(); // still prints 80 even after it got removed?
 }
}
```

Someone knows what is going on here?

Comment: Have you read the help for [remove](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/List/remove.html) method? You should use [removeAt](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/List/removeAt.html) method instead.

Comment: @ΟυιλιαμΑρκευα it worked! If you want you can write it below and I mark it as an answer, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the help for [remove](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/List/remove.html) method? You should use [removeAt](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/List/removeAt.html) method instead.